# Convert Masterpage from hover to onclick for the dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am just learning all this so bear with me.  I have created a master page and right now the dropdown menus open by hovering over them.  Is there a way I can convert this project to open menus and sub menus by clicking on them and NOT hovering over them.  I have look at multiple post on this subject and can't get any of them to work.  The project currently has no javascript and I never tried javascript so if there is away to avoid using java that would be great.  If not then can you point me in that direction.

This is my masterpage (just a small portion of it)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Union County Dispatch Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MenuStyle.css" />
    <style>
        body {
            background-color:gainsboro;
            background-size:cover;
            background-attachment:fixed;
        }

    </style>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <nav>
                <div><img src="~/img/logo2011transparent4.png" runat="server" /></div>
                <label class="toggle" for="drop">Menu</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />

                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Main Menu</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">911 Calltaking Polices</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/County_Polices/Cty_911_calls.aspx")%>">911 For County Police</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Berkeley_Heights/BH_911_calls.aspx")%>">911 For Berkeley Heights</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Cranford/Cr_911_calls.aspx")%>">911 For Cranford</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Fanwood/Fa_911_calls.aspx")%>">911 For Fanwood</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Garwood/Ga_911_calls.aspx")%>">911 For Garwood</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Kean/Kean_911_calls.aspx")%>">911 For Kean Univ.</a><li>
                                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Kenilworth/Ke_911_calls.aspx")%>">911 For Kenilworth</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Roselle_Park/RP_911_calls.aspx")%>">911 For Roselle Park</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scotch_Plains/Sc_911_calls.aspx")%>">911 For Scotch Plains</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Winfield/Wi_911_calls.aspx")%>">911 For Winfield</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            <li><a href="#">CAD Searches</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Sql_Searches/Phone_System_Search.aspx")%>">CAD Search For Backup Phone #'s List</a>
                                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Sql_Searches/Cancellation_Codes.aspx")%>">CAD Search For Cancellation Codes</a>
                                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Sql_Searches/Dispoisiton_Code_Search.aspx")%>">CAD Search For Disposition Codes</a>
                                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Sql_Searches/Hospital_Search.aspx")%>">CAD Search For Hospital Codes And Phone Numbers</a>
                                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Sql_Searches/Skill_search.aspx")%>">CAD Search For Officers Special Skills/Training</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Sql_Searches/Out_Of_Service_Codes.aspx")%>">CAD Search For Out Of Service Codes</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Sql_Searches/Personnel_Search.aspx")%>">CAD Search For Personnel ID And Cell #'s</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Sql_Searches/Powerline_Command_Search.aspx")%>">CAD Search For Powerline Commands</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Sql_Searches/FireEMS_Problem_Natures.aspx")%>">CAD Search For Problem Nature Codes For Fire/EMS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Sql_Searches/Law_Problem_Natures.aspx")%>">CAD Search For Problem Nature Codes For Law</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </ul>
                        <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx")%>">Home</a>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li style="padding-top: 1px; padding-left: 20px;"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtSearch" CssClass="form-control" Font-Size="Medium" Width="200px" OnTextChanged="TxtSearch_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox></li>
                        <li style="padding-top: 1px; padding-left: 8px;"><asp:Button runat="server" ID="BtSearch" Text="Search" CssClass="btn" OnClick="BtSearch_Click" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" /></li>
                    </ul>
            </nav>
            <br />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css code:

```
nav {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

    nav ul {
        float: left;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;

    }

        nav ul li {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
        }

    nav a {
        display: block;
        padding: 3px 15px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: Arial;
    }

        nav a:hover {
            background-color: white;
            color: gray;
        }

    nav ul ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        top: 26px;

    }

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: inherit;
    }

    nav ul ul li {
        float: none;
        display: list-item;
        position: relative;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    }


    nav ul ul ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        left: 300px;
        top: 0px;
        max-height: 1000%;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }

    nav ul ul ul li {
        float: none;
        display: list-item;
        position: relative;

    }


.toggle, [id^=drop] {
    display: none;
}

@media all and (max-width:600px) {
    .menu {
        display: none;
    }

    .toggle {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 20px;
    }

        .toggle:hover {
            background-color: white;
            color: dimgray;
        }

    #logo {
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }

    [id^=drop]:checked + ul {
        display: block;
    }

    nav ul li {
        display: block;
        width: 100%
    }

    nav ul ul {
        float: none;
        position: static;
    }

        nav ul ul ul {
            float: none;
            position: absolute;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete

`nav a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: gray;
}`

Comment: that does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The above is not an option.  Make the above change did not resolve the issue.